# Родственны ли слова?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

А родственны ли слова "граф" и "графин"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Графи́н - в старину карафин, через нем. Karaffine и фр. carafine от итал. caraffina, caraffa, которое, в свою очередь, арабского происхождения: garafa «черпать»- толстостенный сосуд из прозрачного стекла или хрусталя.
ru.wikipedia.org

ГРАФ (нем. Graf) — родовой дворянский титул. В ср.-век. Европе Г. — крупный феодал. С теч. времени стал наследств. или дарованным монархом дворянским титулом. В России титул Г. введен Петром I.
Яндекс.Словари › Гуманитарный словарь, 2002
Этимологический словарь Фасмера:  Ближайшая этимология- уже у Котошихина (30). В качестве русск. титула встречается у Петра I; см. Ф. Браун, Germanica f. Sievers 715. Заимств. из нем. Graf. Более далеко по форме польск. grabia, hrabia, вопреки Смирнову (94). 
*Похоже,  у этих слов просто фонетическое сходство. Это не родственные слова.

Comment: На вики лучше все-таки не ссылаться как на источник этимологических сведений. Но в данном случае, вроде, все правильно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, учту!

Comment: Не обижайтесь, там действительно много непровренного, без ссылки на первоисточник.)))